# how to open file on hackerrank

Tags: c

how to open a text file on hackerrank (c programming )

```
int main() 
{ 
    int a,b;
    scanf("%d\n",&a);
    scanf("%d\n",&a);
    char ch, file_name[25]; 
    FILE fp; 
    char file = "file:\C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\o.txt";
    fp = fopen(file, "r");

    while( ( ch = fgetc(fp) ) != EOF ) 
        printf("%c", ch);

    fclose(fp);
    return 0; 
}
```

**this code is not working on hackerrank**
[image]

Comment: err, `file:\C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\o.txt` is a file from your local computer. Since you're not checking the return code (file cannot be opened), you get an error further on.

Comment: Since you tagged as C++, use `cin >> a;`.  Otherwise, choose your language, C or C++.

Comment: To begin with the file path and name passed to `fopen` is *not* an URL.

Comment: All input come from stdin and all output goes to stdout. There's no need, or capability, to open files there.

Answer (score 2):

No their system doesn't allow that. You can input the file's content on their input box. That serves the purpose always.

Their platform is providing you with a `codepad`, where you will write code and provide input there and the output will be shown. Any interaction with local machine is restricted.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly here

```
char file="file:\C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\o.txt";
```

`file` is declared as `char` and you are assigning it a char array `" "` which is wrong. Declare `file` as `char array` or `pointer`. For e.g

```
char file[1024] = "file:\C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\o.txt";
```

Secondly, hacker rank may not allowing the way you are trying to open the file. Take that point into consideration.

Comment: True, but there are bigger problems with what the OP is trying to do...